# Detect if webpage is being displayed in Facebook Messenger in-app browser on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, messenger

Say I have a webpage that allows the user to play audio. In mobile safari, audio can be played with the ringer off; if opened via Facebook Messenger, the ringer must be on for audio to play. I would like to display a context-aware message to the user reminding them to keep their ringer on in order to hear the audio when my webpage is opened through Facebook Messenger, but not when it is opened in simple Mobile Safari. I have searched through the Facebook developer docs for something like a similar API that kik provides but have not found one.

Is there a reliable way to detect if my webpage is opened in Messenger's in-app browser using an SDK or User-Agents?

Any input/warnings about other apps that also have the 'ringer on' requirement or flaws in my logic would also be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try deeplinking to fb and see if ios provides a callback which could be a hint

Comment: @AvnerBarr could you elaborate more please?

Comment: Ios safari allows deeplinking to installed apps. If the web site is opened through uiwebview i dont think that this would be the case. You could experiment and see if any hints come about

Comment: @AvnerBarr Right, I see. How could I check if iOS provides a callback? I was under the impression from previous experimentation that there is no callback, possibly for security reasons.

Comment: Maybe this? http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Comment: Long shot, did you try to check for the user agent? IIRC iOS adds the app name to the user agent but not sure if this applies to webviews as well

Answer (score 1):

You can check by user agent:

```js
export function isFacebookBrowser() {
  const ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor

  return ua.indexOf('FBAN') > -1 || ua.indexOf('FBAV') > -1
}

export const isMSFamilyBrowser = () => {
  const ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor
  const agent = ua.toLowerCase()

  return agent.indexOf('edge') > -1 || agent.indexOf('edg') > -1 || agent.indexOf('trident') > -1
}
```

Comment: Are these user-agent strings actually used by the Facebook app in iOS? I do see Facebook user-agent strings on Android, but the iOS app appears to use a Webkit based browser that's not specifically Facebook.